# How to execute a .sql script from bash

Tags: mysql, database, linux, bash

Basically, I need to setup a database from a bash script. I have a script db.sql that does all this. Now how do I run this script from bash?

Database system is mysql

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You simply need to start `mysql` and feed it with the content of `db.sql`:

```
mysql -u user -p < db.sql
```

or if you want to select the database right from the command line

```
mysql -u user -p database_name < db.sql
```

Comment: small thing you need to add the dbscrpit path here.

Answer (score 75):

If you want to run a script to a database:

```
mysql -u user -p data_base_name_here < db.sql
```

Comment: Some doubts: 
1) I need to pass the password in command line ?
2) It is possible capture some kind of output from sql file to check a log file for example ?

Comment: @MCunha98 never put a sensitive information like a password in a command. Else it can be found later by going back in the history of previous commands used.

Comment: To output results to a file: `mysql -u user -p data_base_name_here < db.sql > /tmp/output.txt`

Comment: @MCunha98 despite the insecurities, you would simply do `mysql -u user -p"password" data_base_name_here < db.sql`.

Comment: Can we achieve what @MCunha98 asked this using a config file containing passwords?