# Automate MYSQL CREATE DATABASE on terminal

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shell, terminal

I'm running a script I have created that downloads and installs WordPress. To save more time I wanted to open MAMP MYSQL and create a new database like so:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
CREATE DATABASE $1; // passed into the function as argument
exit; // to get out of MYSQL
```

The rest of my function:

```
wordpress() {
  cd /Volumes/example/example/Web/dev;  mkdir $1;
  cd $1;
  curl -O https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz;
  tar -xvzf latest.tar.gz;
  mv wordpress/* .;
  rmdir wordpress/;
  rm latest.tar.gz;
  cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php;
  vim -s /Volumes/example/example/Web/dev/db_overwrite.txt wp-config.php;
  curl -O https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-super-cache.latest-stable.zip;
  curl -O https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-migrate-db.latest-stable.zip;
  curl -O https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.latest-stable.zip;
  curl -O https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-seo.latest-stable.zip
  mv wp-super-cache.latest-stable.zip wp-migrate-db.latest-stable.zip contact-form-7.latest-stable.zip wordpress-seo.latest-stable.zip wp-content/plugins;  
  cd wp-content/plugins;
  cp /Volumes/example/example/Web/Plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro.zip .
  unzip advanced-custom-fields-pro.zip;
  unzip wp-super-cache.latest-stable.zip;
  unzip wp-migrate-db.latest-stable.zip;
  unzip contact-form-7.latest-stable.zip;
  unzip wordpress-seo.latest-stable.zip;
  rm wp-super-cache.latest-stable.zip wp-migrate-db.latest-stable.zip contact-form-7.latest-stable.zip wordpress-seo.latest-stable.zip;
  cd ../themes;
  git clone https://github.com/example/my-template;
}
```

How would I add the MYSQL lines to this function and make it work as intended?

Thanks

Comment: If you're on Linux, read this for instance: https://www.shellhacks.com/mysql-run-query-bash-script-linux-command-line/

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616520/how-to-execute-a-sql-script-from-bash

Comment: @Roadowl these are helpful but I also wanted to dynamically create the database name by argument pass to the function like so: wordpress my_wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -uroot -proot create mydatabase
```

`mysqladmin` is a command-line tool that is part of the standard MySQL client software. It should be present everywhere that the `mysql` tool is present.

You might like to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html

Another alternative is to pass the CREATE DATABASE as an argument to `mysql`:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql ... -e "CREATE DATABASE mydatabase"
```